# increase disk size on virtual box (cent os)

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, disk, diskspace

I need to increase the disk size.

my system is deployed on oracle virtualbox.
I increased the size of the disk in virtualbox on 200+ gb, but in cent os the system disk remained the same size(18 gb).
How do I move the disk space that has appeared to the system drive?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luF5m.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need to do

1. alter your partition table so sda2 ends at end of disk
2. reread the partition table (will require a reboot)
3. resize your LVM pv using pvresize

https://serverfault.com/questions/861517/centos-7-extend-partition-with-unallocated-space